# ubi-partman error 141 clean install kubuntu 16.04 on Thinkpad X201

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, kubuntu, ubiquity

I have some years of experience installing Linux on servers, but, this is my first time trying to test Kubuntu on my thinkpad x201 for regular use

I did

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=10000
```

just to wipe the previous OS in there.

So the disk is clean without any content or partitions in it

But the Kubuntu installer keeps throwing `ubi-partman error 141`

It is a very simple default install, not dual boot. Are there any easy ways to solve this?

I just want something friendly, in order to taste it for a regular user with gmail and youtube, and i dont want a heavy OS, that is why i´m trying Kubuntu.

Comment: Are you using the default automatic installer - Erase.. Install Ubuntu - or are you partitioning it - Something else... -? Update your question either way.

Answer (score 0):

BTW

It Worked running command:

"sudo dmraid -ay"   before running install, since the hard disk was cleaned before install, it´s a little weird for me that the response for the command shows: "RAID set "ddf1_LD1_300" was activated"

maybe is related with the way it discovers ahci adapter, anyway..., the important thing is that it worked!

my .002

Comment: Hi! It looks like you have ended up with two accounts. Please use [the contact form](http://askubuntu.com/contact) to have them merged. Thanks!